# HTML5 FileReader API crashes chrome 17 when reading large file as slice

Tags: html, google-chrome, filereader

I'm trying to read large file (3GB) as slice as 100Mb.

```
      ***function sliceMe() {
            var file = document.getElementById('files').files[0],
            fr = new FileReader;
            var chunkSize = document.getElementById('txtSize').value;
            chunkSize =1048576;            

            var chunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
            var chunk = 0;

            document.getElementById('byte_range').innerHTML = "";

            function loadNext() {
                var start, end,
                blobSlice = File.prototype.mozSlice || File.prototype.webkitSlice;
                start = chunk * chunkSize;
                if (start > file.size)
                    start = end+1;
                end = start + (chunkSize -1) >= file.size ? file.size : start + (chunkSize -1);
                fr.onload = function(e) {      
                    if (++chunk <= chunks) {
                        document.getElementById('byte_range').innerHTML += chunk + "  " +
                            ['Read bytes: ', start , ' - ', end,
                            ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'].join('')+"<br>";                        
                        //console.info(chunk);
                        loadNext(); // shortcut here

                    }
                };
                fr.readAsArrayBuffer(blobSlice.call(file, start, end));

            }
            loadNext();
        }***
```

Above code works as expected in Firefox and in Chrome 16. But in Chrome 17 & 18dev version, after reading 1GB data browser crashes.

Is it known issue in Chrome 17?

Comment: If you have a reproducible crash, please file a bug at http://new.crbug.com/ and post the ID here. I'll ensure it gets in front of the team.

Comment: Issue is filed:Issue #114179:  HTML5 FileReader API crashes chrome 17 when reading large file as slice

Comment: It's funny...I have almost the exact same code and this issue is happening for me too.  Were you able to make any progress with this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem reading in a 1.8 GB file.  If I watch task manager, chrome.exe would take up to 1.5 GB of memory and then crash.  My solution was to use a Javascript worker and then use FileReaderSync instead of FileReader.  The javascript worker runs in a separate thread, and FileReaderSync will only work in a javascript worker.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your algorithm that should change the chunk size run time according to the file size. the google chrome crashes when loop running continuously.