# Cordova fileReader works for text, but returns null for jpgs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, filereader

I'm using an emulation of an android nexus 9 for testing.

I run this code for text, and it works:

```
var filePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "files/newFile.txt";
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath, gotFileEntry, fail);

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    console.log("gotFileEntry: "+fileEntry.name); //"newFile.txt"
    console.log("fileEntry fullpath: "+fileEntry.fullPath); //"/newFile.txt" - cause for concern?
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    console.log("Got the File");
    console.log("Type: " + file.type); //text/plain
    console.log("Path: " + file.fullPath); //undefined
    //path wasn't defined, manually set it
    file.fullPath = fullPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'files/' + file.name;
    console.log("Path: " + file.fullPath); //"file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.myproject123456/files/files/newFile.txt"
    console.log("Bytes: " + file.size); //~14 bytes

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log('Reader status "onloadend": '+reader.readyState); //2 (a.k.a loaded)
        console.log('Result: '+evt.target.result); //"data:text/plain;base64,c26tZSBmaWx1IGrhdGE=" (success)
        console.log('Result: '+reader.result); //"data:text/plain;base64,c26tZSBmaWx1IGrhdGE=" (success)
    };
    reader.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('Error.code: '+reader.error.code) //unused
        console.log('Error.message: '+reader.error.message) //unused
    }
    console.log("Reader status before: "+reader.readyState); //0
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.log("Reader status after: "+reader.readyState); //1
}
```

So I switch it to try and use the picture. Same code, switching "newFile.txt" for "mypicture.jpg":

```
var filePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "files/mypicture.jpg";
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath, gotFileEntry, fail);

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    console.log("gotFileEntry: "+fileEntry.name); //"mypicture.jpg"
    console.log("fileEntry fullpath: "+fileEntry.fullPath); //"/mypicture.jpg" - cause for concern?
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    console.log("Got the File");
    console.log("Type: " + file.type); //image/jpeg
    console.log("Path: " + file.fullPath); //undefined
    //path wasn't defined, manually set it
    file.fullPath = fullPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'files/' + file.name;
    console.log("Path: " + file.fullPath); //"file:///data/data/com.ionicframework.myproject123456/files/files/mypicture.jpg"
    console.log("Bytes: " + file.size); //~3 mega bytes

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log('Reader status "onloadend": '+reader.readyState); //2 (a.k.a loaded)
        console.log('Result: '+evt.target.result); //"null" (FAILURE)
        console.log('Result: '+reader.result); //"null" (FAILURE)
    };
    reader.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('Error.code: '+reader.error.code) //1 (NOT_FOUND_ERR?)
        console.log('Error.message: '+reader.error.message) //undefined
    }
    console.log("Reader status before: "+reader.readyState); //0
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.log("Reader status after: "+reader.readyState); //1
}
```

Using "adb shell" I'm able to show the directory where the files are located. Both files are there. The permissions and owner of both files are the same.

My end goal is to read in a file as a base64 datastream and add it as an attachment to an email using katzer's emailComposer plugin. I'm hoping that I can use this method on an iOS deployment also.

How am I reading this image file incorrectly -- why is reader.readyState returning null?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 3mb is way to big for a dataURL, does a smaller image work? i would also `console.log(e)` in the error handler to get the details.

Comment: @dandavis the plan was to use this method to eventually send up to 25mb zip files -- I'll have to look into the maximum size of dataURLs. I hadn't considered that there may be a maximum length on a stream of data.

I keep getting "e" undefined, so I was using the error.code and looking it up online. I'm new to this language.

Comment: I didn't think that the size would be a problem based on these articles:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706418/are-there-file-size-limitations-when-using-javascript-filereader-api)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.. It was a dunce mistake - the permissions of the image were changed when I overwrote the file when debugging something else.

Comment: what kind of permission you had given. please explain... I am accessing the same image from gallery I am able to access it but same image I am accessing from file manager in this it gives me `reader.result` = null