# Calculate the correct md5 value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, md5

I'm implementing a function to match the md5 value from both frontend and backend.

In the frontend, I'm using SparkMD5 to calculate the md5 value.

However, after trying two files (100mb, 1gb)
Only 100mb file's md5 value could match the value generated from the Mac terminal "md5 FILENAME"

The 1gb file has different values.

Any idea?

## JS code

```
    let readFileT0 = performance.now();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var hexHash = SparkMD5.hash(reader.result);        // hex hash
        console.log("Hex hash:"+hexHash);
        console.log("Time elapsed:");
        console.log(performance.now() - readFileT0)
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with SparkMD5. The problem is the FileReader. It doesn't support such large files. See: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706418/are-there-file-size-limitations-when-using-javascript-filereader-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706418/are-there-file-size-limitations-when-using-javascript-filereader-api)

Comment: Also for more clear information and a solution: [https://medium.com/@0xVaccaro/hashing-big-file-with-filereader-js-e0a5c898fc98](https://medium.com/@0xVaccaro/hashing-big-file-with-filereader-js-e0a5c898fc98)